# My player is not moving correctly, when the key is held down, it should move continuoulsy, but only moves once

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to write something simple in pygame, but this is something I don't understand.
I'm trying to add moving but it's not continuous. I press and hold the key but the key only goes through 1 x_change

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
gDis=pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))

Black=(0,0,0)
White=(255,255,255)
Red=(255,0,0)
Blue=(0,0,255)
Silver=(192,192,192)

clock=pygame.time.Clock()
x=195
y=270
wid=20
hght=20
speed=5

x_change=0
y_change=0
left=False
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                x_change-=5
            

                
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                            x_change=0

        x+=x_change

        gDis.fill(Black)

        pygame.draw.rect(gDis, Silver, (x, y, wid, hght))
        clock.tick(60)

    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You must move and draw the player in the application loop instead of the event loop:

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0

    # INDENTATION

    #<--|

    x += x_change

    gDis.fill(Black)
    pygame.draw.rect(gDis, Silver, (x, y, wid, hght))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thanks man :), I don't know how i didn't see that.